# How do I handle incoming intents from external applications in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, android-intent

i want to open pdf folder in other app without opening my app,I managed to use the intent filter but how to use it, I just added it in the manifest,

I tried searching on flutter, and found a thread discussing it but it's in java and what I need is a pdf (in flutter it's txt)

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? Can't understand what you mean by "i want to open pdf folder in other app without opening my app.". You want to open a pdf file or folder?

Comment: Try looking at [How to receive sharing intents in Flutter?](https://muetsch.io/how-to-receive-sharing-intents-in-flutter.html)